Get ton wallet address from telegram user id
I'm creating a telegram bot, are there any ways to get the TON wallet address by telegram user_id? Is it really possible to fetch it?

No, there is no way to obtain the wallet by the @username.
You have to ask the user to connect to your app with their wallet, for example with ton-connect.

Please see the documentation for how to connect the telegram wallet and obtain all needed info - https://docs.ton.org/v3/guidelines/ton-connect/overview
